# MySQL - SELECT ... WHERE id IN (..) - correct order

Tags: mysql, where-in

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (5,4,3,1,6)
```

and I want to retrieve the elements in the order specified in the `id in..`, meaning it should return:

```
5 ....
4 ....
3 ....
1 ....
6 ....
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You would have to specify a `ORDER BY` with nested `IF` statements, or a calculated field that sets 5 = 1, 4 = 2, 3 = 3..... and order by that

Comment: Thanks.. I'll think I'll do it like that :)

Comment: `FIELD()` is much easier to use. No idea why somebody would like to hurt himself by using `IF`'s or a `CASE`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (5,4,3,1,6) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 5,4,3,1,6);
```

Comment: Clean solution.

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (5,4,3,1,6) ORDER BY FIELD (id, 5,4,3,1,6)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still searching I just found it..

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (4, 3, 1) ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, 4, 3, 1)
```

And a reference for the function you can find [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Answer (score -1):

Well your going to have to create a Id for each of the id's  so:

id   | otherid

1   = 5
2 = 4
3 = 3
4 = 1
6 = 6

using the IN STATEMENT only looks to see if those values are in the List, doesnt order them in any specific order