# How can I display all records where id is equal to 1,2,3,4

Tags: php, mysql

I have inserted multiple id from one table to another table as an array. In database it shows like 1,2,3,4.

My question is how can i display all records where id is equal to 1,2,3,4.

Comment: select * from table where id in (1,2,3,4);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - SELECT ... WHERE id IN (..) - correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090591/mysql-select-where-id-in-correct-order)

Comment: _as an array_... what does your data look like?

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for all numbers between 1 and 4, you can use `BETWEEN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 4
```

If you need specific numbers, you can use `IN()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id IN(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: explain more  your answer for the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try This --

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 1 and 4;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

OR
php array variable
$con is DB connectivity.

```
$id = array[1,2,3,4];

$sql = mysqli_query($con,('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('.implode(", ",$id).')'));
```

Array Inserting data in DB through array

```
$ids = implode(", ",$id);
$sql3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table`(`id`) VALUES ('$ids'");
```

Comment: @pupil : Check now.

Comment: @NicoHaase: Check now.

Comment: `implode(", ", $id` instead of `$id` in your third snippet. Can't print an array like you're currently doing it.

Comment: I have another question. If I inserted an array in one column into the database, how can I display it?

Comment: @VinsmokeSanji : Yes U can Inserting and display.

Comment: How can i retrieve it?